# WPF buttons aren't accessible during an event

Tags: wpf, events, button

I'm having a problem with enabling and disabling buttons in a form I created.

If I toggle the button's state from the event handler, they disable as normal.

```
private void btnBlock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    blockWizard();
}

private void blockWizard()
{
    txtBackupName.IsEnabled = false;
    txtSourceLocation.IsEnabled = false;
    txtDestLocation.IsEnabled = false;
    btnSourceBrowse.IsEnabled = false;
    btnDestBrowse.IsEnabled = false;
    chkRunJobNow.IsEnabled = false;
    txtPassword.IsEnabled = false;
    btnCreateBackup.IsEnabled = false;  
}
```

If I call my blocking method in from a method, it doesn't work.

```
private void SomeEvent()
{
    SomeOtherEvent();
    blockWizard();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as to why this is happening.

Comment: Where is the `SomeEvent` method? In the same class, or in another class?

Comment: if you comment out `SomeOtherEvent();` does `blockWizard();` run as expected?

Comment: Need Mode Explanation and code. To understand your problem fully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your `SomeEvent` method is executed from a thread other than the UI thread. If that is the case, then you cannot update the UI from this other thread.

You could add something like this:

```
private delegate void blockWizardHandler();

private void blockWizard()
{
   if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
   {
       // We are on the UI thread, update the button states
       txtBackupName.IsEnabled = false;
       txtSourceLocation.IsEnabled = false;
       txtDestLocation.IsEnabled = false;
       btnSourceBrowse.IsEnabled = false;
       btnDestBrowse.IsEnabled = false;
       chkRunJobNow.IsEnabled = false;
       txtPassword.IsEnabled = false;
       btnCreateBackup.IsEnabled = false;
   }
   else
   {
       // We are not on the UI thread, invoke delegate to re-run this method on UI thread
       Dispatcher.Invoke(new blockWizardHandler(blockWizard), null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was great help! That's exactly what the problem was, I just wish Visual Studio was a bit more verbose rather than debugging all my code like everything was fine.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. For future reference, when this happens, you should have seen an `InvalidOperationException` printed out to the `Output` window